# Downloading image from url with unicode characters

Tags: java, android, url

I have an application which downloads an image from a given url like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(url).getContent());
```

And it works fine on URL like this:

http://www.test.com/images/test.jpg

But when I try to load an image from this URL:

http://www.test.com/images/מדבר.jpg

It fails and throw an java.io.FileNotFoundException.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to load images with Hebrew characters in their URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to URL-escape these characters.

See this class.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: Is there any function in Java which can do this?

Comment: Yes. Google for "URL encode java" or check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding

Answer (score 0):

You need to [url encode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) your URI or your files. Example:

```
String encodedurl = "http://www.test.com/images/" + URLEncoder.encode("מדבר.jpg","UTF-8");
```